# AWS EC2 Instance health check is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2 Instance health check is failing intermittently but Eureka is UP. Let me know if there is any solution for the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: I currently manage a number of APIs in production on AWS, and some of them also have health which fails sporadically.  It does not seem to be a concern, and is not causing problems for any customers.

Comment: But health check is not changing to pass even after long time. We are rebooting instance multiple times to make it pass.

Comment: OK, in this case you need to do something like check the error logs.  This is possibly the best place to start investigating.